# BMW M41 cold start problems

Tags: bmw, cold-start

I have sometimes this problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvpjEdGH8-A

The engine coughs for a long time before starting ...

I don't understand why, because, sometimes, with the same cold weather and cold engine, it starts very fast. How can that starting time vary so much ?

Comment: Are you allowing the glow plugs to warm the combustion chambers prior to try to start it?

Comment: @Paulster2 : Yes I do...

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the glow plug relay is going out. If it is intermittent, the glow plugs will heat sometimes and other times not. I don't know if this is a known issue with BMW diesels, but it is plausible this is your issue.